# How to insert underbrace in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I am trying to insert underbraces in a mathematical document in a Word 07 document but I can't do it.  Can you please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Have you tried any of the solutions suggested in these [google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+2007+insert+underbrace)?

Answer (score 15):

For anyone else wondering on how to actually get text *beneath* the underbrace, i.e. to label it: You need to type another `_` and then press `SPACE` again. So the correct answer to this question should be:

1. Type "`\underbrace`"
2. Press `SPACE`
3. Type "`_`"
4. Press `SPACE`
5. Either navigate with the arrow keys or click on the placeholders to finish the input.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: thanks a lot! I really do not understand why microsoft haven't added this as usual button.

Comment: This also works in OneNote 2016. Important: the option to insert text above the underbrace only appears once you've pressed another SPACE after the underbrace symbol appeared.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of typing `\underbrace` you can also open `Equation tools` tab, click `Accent` and select underbrace from drop-down menu. It works even in Word 2007

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the Equation Editor.  In Word 2010, click Insert, then Equation. You'll see all the equation tools.

[image] 
To enter an underbrace type "\underbrace", space, the character to go over the underbrace, space, then continue.

Word Help has full details - search for "Equation Editor"

Answer (score 1):

1. Just type in `\underbrace`;
2. Type in "space" (this should turn the `\underbrace` into a proper underbrace);
3. Type in the first character of the expression and "space" again (this should put this character just over the underbrace);
4. Press the left arrow key on your keyboard and then continue typing the rest of the expression.

Comment: Thanks - Have tried but without result.

Comment: @Momoli Did you type this in the equation box after clicking "Insert Equation"?

Comment: Wow !  I have managed to get it .... Thanks very much Jerry !